# Zendesk: How to change zendesk default 100 per_page value

Tags: zendesk

Collections return a maximum of 100 records per page, and by default return 100 records per page. How can I change this default value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set this on a per request basis by passing e.g. per_page=50 in the request parameters. You iterate the collection by incrementing the page attribute, e.g. page=3. Collections also include links in the response body for easier navigation, generally they are on this structure:

```
{
  "users": [ ... ],
  "count": 1234,
  "next_page": "https://account.zendesk.com/api/v2/users.json?page=2&per_page=50",
  "previous_page": null
}
```

Stop paging when the next_page attribute is null.